# ARM Cortex-A7, Secondary Core MMU and Cache Initialization

Tags: caching, arm, multicore, mmu, cortex-a

I am working with the H3 Allwinner SoC. It has 4 cortex a7 processors.

U-boot brings up just one core. I am in the process of bringing up the other cores. However, I am getting stuck trying to initialize the caches and MMUs for the other cores.

In the secondary core boot code, I start by disabling caches and the MMU. I then invalidate the branch predication array and the I-cache. I am then trying to set TTBR0 to point to a pre-made page table with VA=PA flat mappings for my entire address space. However, writing TTBR0 to point to my page table is causing the core to crash, even with the MMU disabled? Any ideas?

Is there some preferred or correct order in initializing this stuff in a secondary core?

Thank you :)